# how to set php_value session.cookie_domain in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I have below line in Apache config,
php_value session.cookie_domain '.domain.com'

I want to convert it into ngixn syntax.

How to set php value session.cookie_domain in nginx config?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what you're trying to achieve - eg "I want to set the value of a header xyz to "abc" for every request that goes through the server / some subset of requests. Please use code blocks for code to make it easy to read. It's probably relatively easy, but you need to be clear what you need. Also let us know if it's a production server that can't have any down time, or if it's a test server.

Comment: Did you check the Nginx docs or search for how to convert Apache syntax to Nginx syntax before asking here?

Comment: There is no "convert it to nginx". It goes into your PHP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your question based on what I think you need, which is simply setting a header for all requests.

First up, you need to build Nginx with the ngx_headers_more module included. I wrote a tutorial that includes how to do that, you can find it [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/). It also tells you how to upgrade a running Nginx install, which would be useful for production.

Once you have nginx built with the required module you need something like this in each of your applicable locations

```
location / {
  add_header header_name "header_value";
  # etc
}
```

Note that you will need this add_header in each location block. There may be a way to set it in a common block, but I don't know what that is.

There are many nginx resources available online, a simple Google search for "nginx how set header" would've answer your question quite simply.